# Networking Event for 75 to 80 people, tables of 6 or 8, 3 rounds

Tags: combinatorics

We are hosting a speed networking event for a group of women business owners.  There will be 75 to 80 people attending.  We will have tables of up to 6 to 8 at each.  There will be 3 rounds.  For each round, each business women talks about her company to the others at the table for 2 minutes.  There after, each gets 2 minutes to talk until the time is done.

For Round 2, everyone changes tables to be able to sit with a completely different group of  people.

Same for Round 3.

What type of formula can we use to figure this out.  We would like to be able to give each person a sheet, telling them which table they are at for each round.

All ideas welcome.  We have done this before, and by the 3rd round, there are overlapping people who have met before.

---

*A suggested rephrasing of the problem (by DGS):*

I am organizing a networking event in which 75-80 people will sit at tables, each of which seats up to 8.  There will be three sessions, and each person can stay or move to a new table between sessions.  How do I assign each person to a table in each session so that by the end each person has met the largest average number of people?

Comment: A suggestion:  Prune your question to its essence so everyone understands it better and is more likely to help.  Does "2 minutes" relate to the problem?  No.  Does "business owners" help?  No.  And avoid ambiguities.  Do some tables seat 6 and others 8?  Or can all (in principle) seat 8, but perhaps 6 will in fact sit?  Posing a good question is half the work, and will get you better answers.

Comment: Try http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html or other related articles.